# Firebase not sorting files alphabetically in android studio,?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using firebase storage for saving images, when I retrieve them on application, files are not sorting alphabetically.
Firebase sorting files by date time, first upload showing on first then second.
I have a lot of files and cannot upload these files one by one.
Is there any way to sort files by alphabetically.
like

```
001.png
002.png
003.png
004.png
005.png
```

…

`

```
private void saveAllSigns() {
    showDialog();
    for (int i = 0; i < SignNameList.length; i++) {
        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(SignNameList[i]);
        int finalI1 = i;
        storageReference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                List<StorageReference> list = listResult.getItems();
                for (StorageReference str : list) {
                    long SIZE = 1024 * 1024;
                    str.getBytes(SIZE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                            saveData(bytes, str.getName(), finalI1);
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.d("SlashLog", "Firebase Exception: " + e.getMessage());

                        }
```

`

looking for solution

Comment: As far as I can tell from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/list-files) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) the `listAll()` call should be returning the files in lexicographical order. Is that not happening for you? Specifically: if you log the `listResult.getItems()` **without download their data**, does it show the results in the order you expect them in?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Firebase documentation given by frank, `listAll()` call should be returning the files in lexicographical order.

Seems order of the files in the list is being changed by the `for` loop that iterates through the list. Maybe you should try sorting the list before iterating through it.

`listAll()` method is being called inside a `for` loop that iterates over the `SignNameList`. If the elements in the SignNameList array are in chronological order, then the `listAll()` method will return the files in chronological order as well.

As also mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#listAll()), Consistency of the result is not guaranteed if objects are inserted or removed while this operation is executing.

Comment: "Firebase Realtime Database does not provide any way to sort data on the server-side" -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data. But the question is about Cloud Storage for Firebase, not the Realtime Database.

Comment: Thanks frank. I have updated my answer now. Please add if i missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answer
but error has resolved from here in data base helper ORDER BY ASC

```
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SIGNS +" ORDER BY fileName ASC", null);
```